# Node JS Sails Two Different Databases

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oracle, sails.js

I'm building an application where I have one local database (mysql), but I need to connect to another database as well so I can pull some information from the second database (oracle), does anyone have any information or examples using Sails to manage multiple databases?

Thanks.

Comment: This "Sails?" http://sailsjs.org/

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good Q&A fit for SO.  Seems like your casting a broad net asking for Sails examples ...  What have you tried, what code?  What's not working.  See SO FAQ

Comment: Found this question (and provided answer!) very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sails uses Waterline as its ORM, and Waterline has a concept of adapters that allow the use of multiple datastores. For each model you create, you can define an **adapter** attribute. So for example if you wanted to create a **User** model that uses mysql as its datastore, it would look something like this.

**In api/models/User.js**

```
module.exports = {

    adapter: 'mysql',

    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        email: 'string',
        phoneNumber: {
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: '555-555-5555'
        }
    }
};
```

You could also then have another model, such as an **Office**, be associated with a different datastore such as mongoDB.

**In api/models/Office.js**

```
module.exports = {

    adapter: 'mongo',

    attributes: {
        address: 'string',
        city: 'string',
        state: 'string'
    }
};
```

The only thing you would need to make sure is that you've installed both **sails-mysql** and **sails-mongo** adapters in your project and have them configured. You can install the adapters with npm.

```
npm install sails-mysql sails-mongo --save
```

You can find out more how to configure the databases at the sails docs for [adapter configuration](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.adapters).

For your particular use case, there is no Oracle adapter as of now. Here is some [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/custom-adapters) and the [boilerplate](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-adapter-boilerplate) to start making a sails adapter if you were interested in starting that project. The list of current available adapters can be found [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/Database-Support).

Comment: does not appear to work if connecting with two different databases on same stack. e.g., mongo but test and test2 databases then having two adapters and specifying in model does not work.. using 10.0.0-rc5

Comment: You can define multiple DB configurations in "config/connnections.js" or "config/adapters.js", even for for multiple databases on same host. Read more about adapters here - http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/config.adapters

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about Sails.js and its Waterline ORM, it doesn't appear that Oracle has a compatible adapter available as of yet.
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline

Comment: Indeed- not yet!  If anyone has an oracle db lying around for us to develop against, it would certainly help

Comment: i suspect you could get away with developing against an oracle XE db.  It is limited as far as CPUs and storage, but otherwise mostly a match with standard AND it is free.